# Guardar varios miembros en la base de datos con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo un sistema de tareas en donde deben estar asignados uno o varios miembros y no se como gardar varios `id` en la columna `miembros` y despues relacionarlos.

Hasta ahora solo logre guardar un miembro, pero no sé como guardar mas `id` dentro de una columna.
Me gustaría aprender bien este tema. Espero haya sido claro.

tabla `trabajo`

```
id(int) | titulo(varchar) | miembrosid(varchar)
----------------------------------------------
1       | Primera nota    | 1, 2
```

tabla `usuario`

```
id(int) | nombre(varchar)
--------------------------
1       | Pedro
2       | Lucas
```

formulario.php

```
<?php

try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pruebas', 'root', '');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
}

if(isset($_POST['add'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['nota'])){
        $add = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO trabajo (titulo, miembros) VALUES (:titulo, :miembros)");
        $add->bindValue(':titulo', $_POST['nota']);
        $add->bindValue(':miembros', $_POST['miembros']);
        $add->execute();
        echo 'Guardado';
    } else {
        echo 'Error';
    }
}

?>

<form action="" method="post">
<div>Titulo</div>
<input type="text" name="nota">

Miembros
<p><input type="checkbox" name="miembros[]" value="1"> Pedro</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="miembros[]" value="2"> Lucas</p>
<button name="add" class="btn btn-primary">Crear</button>
</form>
</form>
```

---- ACTUALIZADO
Pude lograr guardar los `id` separados por `comas`, pero ahora tengo este error cuando quiero listar los nombres de los usuarios

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in order clause is ambiguous in

```
<hr>

<?php

$notas = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM trabajo INNER JOIN usuario ON usuario.id = trabajo.miembros ORDER BY id DESC");

while($row = $notas->fetch()){
?>
<p>
<?=$row['titulo'];?><br>Miembros: <?=$row['nombre'];?>
</p>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Podrías concatenar los `IDs` separandolos con comas, pero lo mejor es que los guardes en otra tabla ej:`notas_miembros(id_nota, id_miembro)` (un miembro por fila), esto te facilitará las cosas cuando consultes la información. Lee acerca de `normalización` en bases de datos relacionales.

Comment: Esa consulta SQL no luce correcta, ¿no querías escribir `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: Si, ahí lo modifiqué. Gracias

Comment: Ejecuta la consulta nuevamente pues con el cambio hecho entonces el mensaje de error no debería ser el mismo

Comment: Ya mofique el error: `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in order clause is ambiguous in`

Comment: El error se debe a que MySQL no sabe de que tabla proviene ese id en esta parte `ORDER BY id DESC");` alcanza con que lo precedas con el nombre de la tabla en la cual existe así: `ORDER BY laTabla.id DESC");`

Comment: Claro, si lo saque, pero ahora solo me da como resultado un usuario

Comment: Eso es un error o comportamiento distinto, te sugiero respondas esta pregunta con la solución propuesta y en todo caso y si es necesario abrir una nueva pregunta al respecto de lo que indicas. Además **no** indiqué quitarlo sino que agregues de que tabla es

Comment: Entiendo, pero el orden es indistinto. Ya no me da ningun error, solo que en vez de listar todos los miembro de un trabajo, me muestra uno solo.

Comment: Entiendo que deberia hacer otra pregunta para solucionar ese tema. Gracias